# How do handle a graceful disconnect with Paho in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, native, mqtt, paho

I need to handle graceful disconnects with the https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-paho-mqtt to a mosquitto broker, and to do that I want to send a "disconnect" message to the broker before actually disconnecting.

Given that in the client supplied by the library there seems to be no callback for the send() function, how can I know that the message has been sent, and only disconnect the client once that has happened? At the moment, the message is only received when I comment out the disconnection line, which means that the disconnection happens before the message is sent.

I was thinking about using a setTimeout, but is that really the best way to go?

```
  const message = new Message(JSON.stringify({payload: 'offline'}));
  message.qos = 2;
  message.destinationName = 'connection/1';
  client.send(message);
  client.disconnect() // <-- if I comment this line out, the message is received
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you are trying to send a message a QOS2 right before disconnecting.

QOS2 messages have a 3 way handshake with the broker to ensure that the message is properly acknowledged by the broker, this requires multiple low level messages to pass back and forth and this is handled asynchronously in the background by the Paho library. By calling disconnect immediately after calling send you are tearing down the MQTT client before this handshake can be completed.

You can use the `onMessageDelivered()` callback to determine when the message has been delivered. See the doc [here](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/jsdoc/Paho.MQTT.Client.html)

Comment: brilliant. does onMessageDelivered() only work when QOS2 is enabled then?

Comment: What does the doc say?

Comment: it says it works in any case, but that's confusing. If there is QOS0, the client doesn't care about whether the message has been delivered. So this option should not work in that case, which is contradictory... (hence my question)

Comment: No, it just means that it will be called as soon as the message is sent, it won't wait for any conformation (which it wouldn't get for a QOS0 message)